# why is my form storing a specific number in the database instead of the numkbers i am giving?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter vaild contact no." maxlength="10" size="10"  name="contact" required>
```

This is my code for the form of phone no. , when i input my phone no. (a 10 digit no).This stores the same number again and again in my database which is not the number i have input.

2147483647:this is what my program is storing in my database.

Comment: phone no is out of range of integer values my friend. Hence, that number.

Comment: Please provide some code how you submit your value to the backend and how you store the data to the database

Comment: show us your table structure

Comment: `int(10)` (signed) has a maximum of 2147483647. Everything over is just to big for the column.

Comment: i have used data type int(10) for phone number

Answer (score 2):

You're most certainly trying to store it as an integer in your database. Phone numbers should never be integers, they'd be enormous numbers! They should always be treated as strings. You're not planning to do arithmetics on a phone number.

The specific number you're giving us is the largest signed 32-bit integer. Your phone number is just too large to handle.

Comment: yes i have used datatype int(10).which data type do u suggest for phone number

Comment: @abharawat a String

Comment: If you're using MySQL, varchar would be the one.